# Is it possible to align only one div in a bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that I would like to `display: inline`. Of course it's no problem with 2 `col-md-6` sections, but what if I wanna do that with only one? Is there a way?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <article <?php post_class('list-item'); ?>>
    <div class="list-item">
     <div class="list-img">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else { echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/placeholder-content-list.jpg' . '" alt="No Picture" />'; } ?></a>
     </div>
     <div class="desc-list">
      <header class="list-header">
       <?php mh_newsdesk_lite_post_meta(); ?>
       <h3 class="list-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      </header>
      <div class="list-excerpt">
       <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are saying that when you add another column without being lined with the first column, use another `.row`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I have a list of articles that I want to place next to each other, but I cant just split the article into two cols, because it just duplicates the list...

Comment: Could you show on some screen what effect do you want to achieve? I'm not sure if I understand you right

Comment: This is the article template. And of course you can only have one, so I need to split this one section to be displayed inline...

Comment: You want to display `container-fluid` as `inline`?

Comment: With offset class, it creates spaces both in left and right of the element. Also look at this link
[Bootstrap column aligning](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this. Use offset.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <p>Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-offset-3"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

or

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
       <p>Text Text Text</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

or

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
       <p>Text Text Text</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

If I understand you right?

Comment: there is no need to create separate div for col-*-offset-* , You can use it in same as col-*-*

Answer (score 0):

You should use offset class. like this

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <p>This is testing text</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Find out the grid system on  Bootstrap page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options